# Change the color of the bar chart based on the value

Tags: highcharts

I want to ask in this jsfiddle there is a bar chart whose color changes based on the value, but if the bar has been highlighted with the cursor / pointer the color changes to the initial color again, how do you keep the color based on the value?

this the link to jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/upz5q2fd/7/

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' millions'
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Year 1800',
            color: 'yellow',
            data: [107, 31, 635, 203, 2]
        }]
    },function(chart){
    
        var max = 200;
        
        $.each(chart.series[0].data,function(i,data){
            
            if(data.y > max)
                data.graphic.attr({
                    fill:'red'
                });
            
        });
    
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing color by attribute, define it on a point level in data, for example:

```
    var data = [107, 31, 635, 203, 2];
    var processedData = data.map(function(dataEl, index){
        return {x: index, y : dataEl, color: dataEl > 200 ? 'red' : 'yellow'}
    });

    $('#container').highcharts({
        ...,
        series: [{
            ...,
            data: processedData
        }]
    });
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/L7wgcmd1/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.bar.data.color